# Correctly adding WordPress blog to existing site

Tags: seo, google, google-search, optimization

I have a website running and have added an extra link on the website that links to a WordPress site.

Both sites are hosted on the same domain. Here's my problem;

The domain:
`www.example.com`

The Wordpress blog:
`www.blog.example.com`

Mmy gut is telling my that for best SEO practices I need the domain to be:
`www.example.com/blog/....`

But when setting up my WordPress site it made an entirely new sub-domain. Is this OK or should I find out how to make the WordPress site link to `www.example.com/blog`?

Comment: "**it** made an entirely new sub-domain." - _What_ made the subdomain? How did you install WP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up a blog on a subdomain compared to a subdirectory really shouldn't make too much of a difference in terms of SEO.  It truly depends on the Webmaster's preference.  Google and other search engines "should" treat each of them the same granted they again,

- have the same Copyright information
- Are using the same Google Search Console (formerly Webmaster Tools) account

Answer (score 1):

www.blog.website.com will be treated as a completely separate domain.

So:

**www.blog.website.com and www.website.com will not share each other's domain authority.**

Also its very much easy to configure wordpress however you want. So you should ideally go with www.website.com/blog so that you can link you blogs better and pass more SEO juice from parent site to blog site and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up a subdomain for a blog is absolutely fine from an SEO standpoint.   Google treats subdomains as the same site when:

- They interlink to each other
- The have the same copyright info
- They are added to the same Google Search Console account

If it is easier to set up the blog on a subdomain from a technical standpoint, there is no SEO reason why you shouldn't do so.